# Disable checkbox after clicking button on ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, checkbox, click

I'm making an Ionic app and I'm creating profiles grups on it. To do this, the user needs to choose profiles from a checkbox list, then click a button and the group is created. At this point, those profiles already selected should disappear or at least should be unable to click them, but I can't do it.
Code:
HTML

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let profile of profiles; let i = index">
     <ion-label>{{profile.name}}</ion-label>
     <ion-checkbox color="dark" [(ngModel)]="values[i]"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<button ion-button full (click)="addGroup()">Add group</button>
```

TS

```
profiles = [];
values = [];
groupList = [];

addGroup(){
let y=0;
for(let i=0; i<this.values.length; i++){
  if(this.values[i] == true){
    this.groupList[y] = this.profiles[i];
    y++;
  }
}
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Group created!',
  buttons: ['OK']
});
alert.present();

//I tried this to solve the problem, but it is not really what I want...
for(let i=0; i<this.values.length; i++){
  if(this.values[i] == true){
    this.profiles[i] = 0;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to loop over values but it is an empty array. Seems like you're missing core programming concepts here.

Comment: Obviously, there are no empty arrays. Didn't put that code because is not what is important.